# Scaling and Positioning Image Effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ocinisme/vqAwJ/5/

Practically what I want to achieve is that all the small red boxes one by one scaled up to the center of the screen , and then scaled down to its original position , then go and placed inside the grey frame.

The concept is all the small red boxes in the end will be placed inside the frame. I am open to any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you actually mean this behavior,

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('button').attr('disabled', 'true');
    $('#a').animate({
        width: '100px',
        height: '100px',
    }, 1500, 'linear', function() {
        $('#a').animate({
            width: '30px',
            height: '30px',
        }, 1500, 'linear', function() {
            $('#a').animate({
                top: '165px',
            }, 1500, 'linear', function() {
                $('#b').animate({
                    width: '100px',
                    height: '100px',
                }, 1500, 'linear', function() {
                    $('#b').animate({
                        width: '30px',
                        height: '30px',
                    }, 1500, 'linear', function() {
                        $('#b').animate({
                            top: '205px',
                        }, 1500, 'linear', function() {
                            $('#c').animate({
                                width: '100px',
                                height: '100px',
                            }, 1500, 'linear', function() {
                                $('#c').animate({
                                    width: '30px',
                                    height: '30px',
                                }, 1500, 'linear', function() {
                                    $('#c').animate({
                                        top: '245px',
                                    }, 1500, 'linear');
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

​

Look at the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thujeevan/vqAwJ/6/)

Comment: Yes it is something like this, but is there any efficient way to do this? I am thinking of something like what you did as well, but I am afraid that it might not be efficient.